# Acessar índice negativo de um array

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, característica-linguagem

#### BUG?

Estava construindo uma biblioteca para tratamento de Arrays e me deparei com a seguinte situação: Ao incluir um valor à um índice negativo dentro do meu Array, este índice não aparece ao utilizar alguns métodos:

#### Exemplo:

```
var array = new Array("Maria", "João", "Carlos");
array[-3] = "Bernardo";

console.log(array[-3]); //Bernardo
console.log(array.length); //3
console.log(JSON.stringify(array)); //"["Maria", "João", "Carlos"]"
```

Note-se que a quantidade continua como 3 ao utilizar `length` e o método `JSON.stringify` mostra apenas os 3 originais, porém, ao exibir no console o `array[-3]` o nome vem corretamente.

#### Pergunta:

O correto não seria aparecer `length = 4` e aparecer no método `JSON.stringify`? Porque isso ocorre? Seria algum tipo de *bug* a linguagem me permitir adicionar um valor à um índice negativo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em [ECMAScript](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) (base do JavaScript e ActionScript) arrays não são "especiais" de nenhuma forma: são apenas um objeto normal com um atributo `length`. Isso significa que:

- Internamente, suas chaves são strings, não inteiros:

  ```
  var arr = [10, 20, 30];
  console.log(arr[0]);   // 10
  console.log(arr["0"]); // também 10
  ```
- Pode-se adicionar qualquer propriedade adicional que você quiser:

  ```
  var arr = [10, 20, 30];
  arr.teste = 42;
  console.log(arr.teste);    // 42
  console.log(arr["teste"]); // 42
  ```

Em geral, objetos que possuem o tipo `Array` se encarregam de atualizar seu `length` conforme propriedades numéricas (não negativas) são adicionadas. Isso ocorre independentemente delas serem adicionadas com o `push`, com um índice numérico ou com um índice string:

```
var arr = [];  // length: 0
arr.push(10);  // length: 1
arr[1] = 20;   // length: 2
arr["2"] = 30; // length: 3
arr[10] = null; // length: 11
```

Mas se você adiciona outras propriedades, de qualquer tipo, ele considera que isso é apenas uma propriedade "normal" - que não tem nada a ver com arrays - e não mexe no `length`:

```
arr.foo = "bar"; // length: 11
arr["foo"] = 42; // length: 11
arr["+"] = 9001; // length: 11
arr["-3"] = 123; // length: 11
```

É por isso que se pode acrescentar elementos num "índice negativo": pois o ECMAScript não considera isso como um "índice", mas apenas como uma propriedade normal.

[Exemplos no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r848u/). No console do Chrome, ele mostra não só os índices posicionados mas também as propriedades "avulsas". Ex.: `[10, 20, 30, 10:null, foo:"bar"]`

Comment: Um link para descrição do ECMAScript cairia bem! Rsrs. Não sabia que o Javascript e o ActionScript eram providos desta linguagem, agora fica mais claro ainda a semelhança entre eles. Em relação ao Array, entendo agora que `-3` é tratado como `"-3"` sendo um valor de um Objeto e não um índice de um Array e que o objeto Array das linguagens são também um "subtipo" de um objeto comum.

Comment: Testei também com valor Booleano `array[true] = "Abner;"`, ele trata como um 'objeto normal'! Muito estranho e ao mesmo tempo interessante! Rsrs

Comment: @biio Ele aceita até mesmo `null` e `undefined` como chaves... :P (baita potencial para erros, aliás)

Comment: Mas @biio, atenção que a chave é sempre convertida para string, portanto `"true"`, `"null"` ou `"undefined"`.

Comment: @bfavaretto De fato. Inclusve, ao se usar um objeto como chave (digamos, `arr[{ foo:"bar" }]`) o que é usado é sua representação como string (`arr["[object Object]"]`). Outro potencial pra erros...

Comment: Pois é. Na próxima versão (ES6), haverá [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) e [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap), que aceitarão objetos de verdade como chaves.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays em Javascript não possuem índices negativos.

O que acontece aqui é que você está criando uma nova propriedade no objeto `Array`, de nome "-3".

Acontece a mesma coisa se você utilizar uma palavra. Por exemplo:

```
var v = new Array("abra", "cadabra", "alacazan");
v["-5"] = "isto não é um índice";
v["banana"] = "muito menos isto";
v[-7] = "nem isto";

v.length // 3
v["-5"] // "isto não é um ndice" 
v.banana // "muito menos isto"
v["banana"] // "muito menos isto"
v["-7"] // "nem isto"
```

Comment: Discordo... Ao inserir um número positivo dentro do array, como por exemplo `array[3] = "Teste"`, automaticamente o índice `3` do meu array aparece ao utilizar os métodos `JSON.stringify` e `array.length`... (`"["Maria", "João", "Carlos"]"` e `4`, respectivamente)

Comment: Claro, pois 3 é um índice válido. "-3" não.

Comment: @beterraba vc ta querendo dizer que -3 é visto como a string "-3" na hora de setar o valor pro índice ? então porque quando eu tento v[-a] da erro ? era pra ele entender -a como string seguindo sua linha de raciocínio.

Comment: @TuyoshiVinicius `1` também é visto como a string `"1"`, mas é um índice válido.

Comment: @TuyoshiVinicius Por que -a é ambíguo. O interpretador encara `a` como uma variável. Observe que eu setei, no meu exemplo, `v[-7]` e acessei `v["-7"]`.

Comment: Beterraba, todos os índices são strings. Veja a resposta do mgibsonbr, são propriedades normais, mas com tratamento especial.

Comment: @TuyoshiVinicius onde `v[-a]` dá erro? No Chrome pelo menos ele funciona normalmente...

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, eu sei. Só complementei o seu comentário.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Pode ser que os logs do seu chrome esteja desabilitado porque aqui eles diz que "a" é uma referencia não definida, que obviamente é rsrs https://cdn.anonfiles.com/1407177293387.jpg

Comment: @TuyoshiVinicius hahaha ok! É que no meu caso eu defini `a`... :P (tanto como positivo quanto negativo; veja o jsFiddle no final da minha resposta)

Answer (score 1):

Eu achei a resposta do @mgibsonbr correta, mas um pouco confusa. Vou deixar minha contribuição, uma tradução e adaptação de [uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13618751) do SOEn, que deixa mais evidente para os burricos do JavaScript como eu. >.<

---

Quando se referencia diretamente um índice ou posição, os valores são adicionados ao array:

```
var array = [];

array[0] = "Foo";
array[1] = "Bar";

// Result: ["Foo", "Bar"]
// Length: 2
```

O que não é o caso quando referenciando índices negativos:

```
var array = [];

array[0]  = "Foo";
array[1]  = "Bar";
array[-1] = "Fizzbuzz"; // Índice inválido - Pega, Rex! Pega!

// Result: ["Foo", "Bar"]
// Length: 2
```

Os valores somente serão adicionados se você brincar de acordo com as regras. Se não seguí-las, os valores não vão ser adicionados. Simples assim!

Mas apesar de não serem aceitas como parte do conjunto de dados, as informações associadas à indíces negativos são aceitas **pelo objeto Array** e, por isso ainda é possível acessar esse valor, como qualquer outra propriedade:

```
array[-1]; // "Fizzbuzz"
```

Quando construímos um objeto Array, mesmo que não tenhamos definido nenhum valor para ele, ele não está vazio, afinal, todos os métodos pertencentes ao objeto, sejam eles nativos ou prototipados já estão lá a disposição e podem, inclusive, ser acessados da mesma forma:

```
array["pop"]; // function pop() { [native code] }
```

Aqui acessamos o índice **prop** que não é um índice válido para o cojunto de dados, mas é válido como propriedade do objeto Array e está associado o código nativo [Array.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

E por isso propriedade como `length` e métodos como [Array.prototype.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) ou [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), que trabalham unicamente com índices inteiros e positivos mostram resultados diferentes do que você espera.

Mais uma vez, pra reforçar. O valor não está **no array** e sim **no objeto** *Array*.

Comment: Eu não sei, pra mim confunde mais pensar em "o array" versus "o objeto array". Os dois são uma coisa só. O segredo está no `length`, que na verdade é um getter e setter, e não uma propriedade comum.

Comment: Ao resgatar os itens do Array também! Assim como transformar o Array em JSON! É um pouco confuso mas entendo agora que há um objeto por trás desse Array!

Comment: Ao contrário. Em JavaScript pelo menos, Array é um objeto. Aquilo que iteramos e referenciamos por índices é uma mera coleção de dados. Mas sim, você entendeu. ^_^